# What do you means KB/sec?

Tags: jmeter

we have got TOTAL

```
Label:    10    
Average:  1288
Median:   1278  
90%:      1525  
95%:      1525  
99%:      1546  
Min:      887   
Max:      1546  
Throughput: 6.406149903907751   
KB/sec:     39.21264413837284
```

What do means of means KB/sec? please help me understand ot it

Comment: Just a wild guess: kilobytes per second

Comment: It's the security mechanism behind Microsoft's KnowledgeBase articles, hence KB/sec :-) Just kidding. As I'm sure the tool is kidding that it can measure these figures down to a 1/10billionth of a byte.

Comment: I did not understand what do you means kB/sec 39.212644 is it first Byte load time or whole website byte load time

Comment: **Kb/sec** - The **throughput** measured in **Kilobytes per second**.you should read the [JMeter User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Glossary](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420385-Glossary)

> **KB/s(Aggregate Report)**
>
> Throughput is measured in bytes and represents the amount of data that the Virtual users received from the server.Throughput KPI is measured in kilobytes(KB) per seconds.

So basically it is average amount of data received by JMeter from the application under test per second.

Answer (score -1):

KB/sec is the speed of a connection.
KB meaning Kilobyte and sec meaning per second
You get faster speeds of MB/sec which is Megabyte and even faster speeds of GB/sec which is Gigabytes

1000 KB = 1 MB
1000 MB = 1 GB

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I did not understand what do you means kB/sec 39.212644 is it first Byte load time or whole website byte load time

Comment: it means the site is loading at 39 KB/sec 39 kilobytes per second.